# Picking only range of commits while merging into another branch in git

Tags: git

feature branch 1

```
1
2
3 - this commit changed more than 1000 files
4
5
6 - this commit changed more than 1000 files
7
8
9
10
```

i am parallely working on another feature . Until 10th commit i was pulling all the code from feature branch 1.

Now , due to 3rd and 6th commit, there are so many conflicts while doing git merge.

So, is it possible to leave 3rd and 6th commit alone while merging to feature-branch2

or is there a way to pick commits from 9 to 1 excluding 3 and 6

or can we do step by step like [9-7], [5-4], [2-1]

please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You could try removing or reverting the commits you don't want in your source branch, before merging into the target branch.  As safety precautions, you may want to create a new branch from `feature1`, and also use `git revert` to undo the unwanted commits:

```
# from feature 1
git checkout -b feature1_a
git revert 3^..6
git push origin feature1_a
```

Replace `3` and `6` above with the SHA-1 hashes of the older and newer commit in the range you want to revert.

Then, issue a pull request from `feature1_a` to the target branch.

Answer (score 0):

First an obvious asumption : if you ask to remove commits "3" and "6", you know that you can discard the modifications from these commits -- not just "discard them because they are annoying to me".

---

You can use `git rebase -i {1}` (replace "1" by the hash of commit `1` in your diagram).

Executing this command will open a file in a text editor :

```
pick 2   commit message
pick 3   commit message
pick 4   commit message
pick 5   commit message
pick 6   commit message
pick 7   commit message
pick 8   commit message
pick 9   commit message
pick 10  commit message

# Rebase 31ae65d16..b31f500e4 onto 31ae65d16 (30 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
#   ...   instructions to edit the history above
```

In this file, delete the lines "3" and "6", save and exit.

The result will be a branch, with all commits except "3" and "6".